# Rust: Could not compile cfg-if

Tags: rust

I am trying to compile my Rust project, which has a dependency on `cfg-if` crate.

```
cargo rustc --verbose --release --target armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf -- -C link-arg=-Wl,-Bdynamic -C link-arg=-Wl,patched_libs/libapplibs.so -C link-arg=-Wl,patched_libs/libc.s
```

It fails with the following error (verbose) :

```
rustc --crate-name cfg_if --edition=2018 /home/<user>/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-f1e60147b9cdaa30/cfg-if-0.1.10/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -Cembed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=edabb55f2437adf3 -C extra-filename=-edabb55f2437adf3 --out-dir '<outdir>' -L 'dependency=<outdir>' --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to build archive: No such file or directory
```

I am using nightly channel but I see the same behavior with stable.

```
rustc 1.47.0-nightly (6e87bacd3 2020-07-31)
```

How do I even debug this?

Comment: Try to disable these optional dependencies: https://github.com/alexcrichton/cfg-if/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L21

Comment: Can it be related that [`armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf`](https://forge.rust-lang.org/release/platform-support.html#tier-2) might not have the full binary support? Sorry I know nothing about embed

Comment: @RobinLindner, that worked. I removed both `core` and 'compiler_builtins`, which are listed as optional dependencies. Do you mind explaining why this fix works? I am having similar errors in other crates, perhaps repeat this trick?

Comment: @SriharshaMadala I guess this works because the rust-core of version 1.0.0 is given in the dependencies and the current version is not 1.0.0.

Comment: update: I tried compiling another crate which depends on bindgen which depends on cfg-if. This time I set the default target to rule out potential issues caused by special target. I see the same behavior. On first failure, I remove the optional dependencies and the build fails at lazy_static compilation. On reissuing the build command, I see the failure is back at cfg-if. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: update: the issue is resolved. When I cloned my repo, it had `%20` for spaces. When I renamed my repo, I was able to clean-build without any issues. It is weird that none of the error prints were helpful and that it partially compiles.